# Running CMD as Admin on a Standard User on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe, non-admin, bypass, standard-user

The limitations I have right now are the fact that I can't run or install new programs. I don't want to reset the Administrator password. How can I do this?

Comment: Why post the same question twice?

Comment: Are you actually authorized to have administrative capabilities on this machine, or are you trying to subvert existing security policies without anyone's knowledge?

Comment: I'm trying to do this for educational purposes. That's it.

Comment: Thought it would be best to have different questions for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If you need administrative privileges, you need an account that has them. If you do not have this on your pc, the only thing you can do is reinstall windows so you can get a fresh install with administrative privileges.

If you (or anyone else has access to the admin account) you can just right-click "run as administrator" and you'll get a login prompt to login using that administrator account. An administrator can grand you admin access to one program by using the following program: [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/08/get-rid-of-uac-prompts-with-microsofts-application-compatibility-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the admin password there's nothing you can do. This is by design.

Do you mean without resetting the password? If you've lost the admin password and need to do a recovery you'll have to create a password reset disk. Note that this only works if you're not part of a domain.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/create-password-reset-disk#1TC=windows-7

Comment: It is supposed to say without. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

To launch an executable with administrative privileges from a standard user account, you need to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *right click* the executable file and select **Run as different user**.

[image]

This will allow you to enter the username and password of an administrative user on the machine to run the program.

**Note:** if the option doesn't show up in the start menu, navigate to the .exe file and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *right click* on that.

Comment: If there is no other user to run as that has admin privileges, do I have another choice for what to do?

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine, you can try to [enable the built-in Administrator account](https://4sysops.com/archives/offline-enable-the-windows-8-built-in-administrator-account/), fix things, and then disable it again.

Comment: I've tried searching it up. To enable the built in admin with: net user administrator /active:yes, I need to have admin rights.

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine, you can gain admin rights via a recovery disk. If you don't have physical access to the machine, then this is by design. A non-admin user should never be able to gain admin access without an admin granting it. (Physical access to a machine implies administrative access)

Comment: Can you link me to a thread talking about the how to set up the recovery disk?

Comment: You can use a Windows Installation Disk as a generic recovery disk. Creation of a dedicated recovery disk customized to a particular machine requires administrative privileges and might require the install disk to copy files if they're not stored locally on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through a live boot sequence to get SYSTEM privileges locally but I'm not going to explain why because

1. Your reasoning for you you're doing this seems suspiciously weak
2. I've literally already answered this question on a Stack Exchange forum. If you really want to, you can dig through my profile to the answer.

SYSTEM is even higher than admin, and it would allow you to make a new administrator account.